# Nightly automation with Visual Studio

Tags: macos, selenium, testing, automation

I have finally gotten my testing framework and testing suite of selenium tests working on OS X via Visual Studio for Mac Preview. I'm looking for a solution to have all these tests run nightly at a specific time for regression. How would I go about doing this on OSX? On windows I used `vstest.console.exe` and made a batch file that I had the task scheduler kick off every night.

I'm fairly new to OS X so Im not sure where to begin on what tools/programs that could accomplish this. I have tried NUNIT-CONSOLE but it was a dead end and it just wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should try with [automator](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/schedule-automator-tasks-mac-os-x-39132.html) or [cron](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html), but I would recommend you to start using [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) instead of OS schedulers.